# PHP move_uploaded_file doesn't work occasionally?

Tags: php

I now there are lots of same questions here, but I didn't find my answer.

I want to upload an image using **move_uploaded_file()** function in PHP. Here is my logic?

```
//check if file uploaded
if (!isset($_POST) || !isset($_FILES)) {
    return back();
}

// allowed extensions
$extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];


$fileName = pathinfo($_FILES['profile-image']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

// save file extension into a variable for later use
$parts =  explode('.',$_FILES['profile-image']['name']);
$extension = strtolower(end($parts));

$fileSize = $_FILES['profile-image']['size'];

// check the extension
if (!in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
    return back()->withErrors(['File Extension is not valid']);
}

// check if file size is less than 2MB
if ($fileSize >= 2e+6) {
    return back()->withErrors(['File Size is too large.']);
}



//check if there is other errors
if ($_FILES['profile-image']['error']) {
    return back()->withErrors(['You have anonymus error']);
}

// generate a unique file name
$profile_image = Hash::make($fileName) . '-' . time() . '.' . $extension;

// make a directory if there isn't one
if (!is_dir('public/img')) {
    mkdir('public/img');
}


// if current user has an image then delete it
$user = App::get('database')->find('users', compact('id'));

if ($user->profile_image) {
    unlink('public/img/' . $user->profile_image);
}


// move image into directory and final check for errors
if( ! move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile-image']['tmp_name'], 'public/img/' . $profile_image) ) {
    return back()->withErrors(['Your file doesn\'t uploaded']);
}


// Insert Uploaded Image into DB.
App::get('database')->update('users', compact('id'), compact('profile_image'));


return redirect('dashboard')->withMessage('Thank for uploading the file.');
```

I try this code, everything works properly but just sometimes. I don't know why sometimes my uploaded file doesn't move to the directory and sometimes it does. I tried for the same image, sometimes it uploaded and sometimes it failed. This is interesting, because when I upload an image and it fails, can't catch any errors at all.

Comment: Use this, "if (!isset($_POST) && !isset($_FILES)) {
    return back();
}", previous one will drop if any one fails !

Comment: @Shankar Which, I think, is the intention…! Aside: `$_POST` will always be "set". It may be *empty* though, which you should check with `if (!$_POST)`.

Comment: @deceze, You are right, but in case of file upload with form. Both should pass, $_POST will just show the name of the file . $_FILE only returns the instance to access media. So this only can ensure that, we are in right way to handle media content....

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan It's not because of "$_POST".

Answer (score 1):

Did you check ***max_file_uploads*** and ***post_max_size*** in your php.ini file ?

Maybe the file is bigger than the maximum size allowed.

Regards.

Comment: I checked both, max_file_uploads is about the maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a **single request**. And post_max_size is 20MB. :(

Answer (score 1):

OK, I find the problem. When I hash the image name and save it to DB, sometimes it includes **/** inside file name, then when I use the file name in image **src** attribute, it considers the part before the / as another directory.

Answer (score 0):

It might have trouble with,

- Your **Destination Directory** have some writing **permission issue**.

Try this for manage file permission,

```
     if (!is_writable($url)) {
        try {
            chmod($url, 0644);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage() . ' | File : ' . $url . ' | Needs write permission [0644] to process !');
        }
    }
```

All the Best !

Comment: Thanks, but It's not about the permission because sometimes it uploads and nothing goes wrong.